# Cannot understand a sed pattern

Tags: bash, loops, sed, block

My original issue was to be able to add a line at the end of a specific block in a configuration file.

```
############
# MY BLOCK #
############
VALUE1 = XXXXX
VALUE2 = YYYYY
MYNEWVALUE = XXXXX      <<< I want to add this one

##############
# MY BLOCK 2 #
##############
```

To do this I used the following sed script and it work flawlessly (found it in another post) :

```
sed -i -e "/# MY BLOCK #/{:a;n;/^$/!ba;i\MYNEWVALUE = XXXXX" -e '}' myfile
```

This worked perfectly when executed inside a shell script but I can't manage to use it directly in an interactive shell (it gave me an error: "!ba event not found"). To solve this, I tried to add '\' before '!ba' but now it gave me another error which tells me that '\' is an unknown command.

**Could anyone explain where my mistake is on the above issue and how this script works?**

Here is my understanding:

```
-i : insert new line (i think the first one is useless, am i right?)
-e : execute this sed script (don't understand why there is a second one at the end to close the })
:a : begin a loop
n : read each line with the pattern ^$ (empty lines)
! : reverse the loop
ba : end of the loop
```

Thanks !

Comment: `-i` is short for `--in-place` (replace input file with modified content), `-e` is short for `--expression`. Reading `man sed` would have revealed that (and more) to you.

Comment: I did it, thanks for the reply. I only wanted to know how sed does his work, as you can see my -i and -e are near of the man description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `:a` introduces a label, named `a`.
- `n` writes current pattern space to output, and replace pattern space with next line of input.
- `/^$/!` means to match lines that are *NOT* (`!`) blank lines in pattern space; the following `ba` is a "branch to label a" when that match (not blank line) occurs.
- If the branch doesn't occur, the `i` insert then takes place.

Use single quotes (') instead of double quotes (") on command line to prevent shell from performing shell substitutions (including the "$" and "!" characters).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For "n" when you mean it write/replace the pattern, does it act like a "read" ? I mean as you can read lines from a simple file?

Comment: yes: you're writing the current "buffer" (last line read + changes, such as the insert) and reading the next line of input.

Answer (score 1):

Use `'` instead of `"` to avoid having bash try to do history substitution on the `!`

If `XXXXX` contains a shell parameter expansion or somesuch, you can do it like this:

```
sed -i -e"/# $BLOCK_NAME"'#/{:a;n;/^$/!ba;i\'"$NEW_VAR = $NEW_VALUE" -e"}" myfile
```

The second `-e` is required to effectively insert a newline to close off the `i` command. You could actually insert the newline directly, instead:

```
sed -i -e"/# $BLOCK_NAME "'#/{:a;n;/^$/!ba;i\'"$NEW_VAR = $NEW_VALUE"$'\n}' myfile
```

Comment: I don't know too for the second -e, i tried your code and it give me "sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'". With the second -e it works perfectly but i don't know why it is needed.

Comment: @Arka: I looked at it again, and updated my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In interactive shells, `!` is used for history substitution, so you need to escape it:

```
sed -i -e "/# MY BLOCK #/{:a;n;/^\$/\!ba;i\MYNEWVALUE = XXXXX" -e '}' myfile
```

You should also escape `$`, since it has special meaning inside doublequoted strings (although in this case it's OK, because it's followed by `/`, not a variable name).